# SoapUI how to Update WSDL Definition and Recreate requests through Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a soap test Project in SoapUI. I have added all the requests as test steps in a test suite.

I need that the WSDL definition gets updated and requests get recreated (while keeping existing values) every-time i start the test.

I need help to do this process automatically with help of a groovy script that can be placed inside the project and runs every-time before execution starts.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working now..
Here is the complete code..

```
import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateRequests
import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateTestRequests

project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project; //get the project reference
def ifaceList = project.getInterfaceList(); //get all the interfaces present in the project in a list

//start a loop for number of interfaces
for(int i = 0; i < project.getInterfaceCount() ; i++)
{

def iface = project.getInterfaceAt(i);
def url = iface.definition;
iface.updateDefinition( url, true); //updateDefinition(String url , Boolean createRequests)

//The above part updates the definition
//The part below recreates the requests based on updated wsdl definition

//syntax - 
//recreateRequests( WsdlInterface iface, boolean buildOptional, boolean createBackups, boolean keepExisting, boolean keepHeaders )

recreateRequests(iface,true,true,true,true);
recreateTestRequests(iface,true,true,true,true);
}
//End of Script//
```

Hope this helps others looking for similar solution.

Comment: If you want that only the requests that got updated should be backed but update the following line.                     
.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                .                                                                                
`iface.updateDefinition( url, false);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an updated wsdl file in hand, then you use [*UpdateWSDLDefinition.groovy*](https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/blob/master/groovy/UpdateWSDLDefinition.groovy) script to update the *service interface* & *test requests* of test case of the project. .

```groovy
/**
*This script automatically update the wsdl definition and its test requests in the soapui project
*Check for the variables- projectName, wsdlFiles to be updated before running the script
*/
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Interface
import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateRequests
import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateTestRequests
/**
* Created by nmrao on 12/24/14.
*/
class UpdateWsdls {

       WsdlProject wsdlProject

        public UpdateWsdls(String projectFileName) {
            this.wsdlProject = new WsdlProject(projectFileName)
        }

        def getBindingNames(String wsdlFile) {
            def definitions = new XmlParser().parse(new File(wsdlFile))
            return definitions.getByName('*:binding').@name
        }

        void updateInterfaceDefinitions(List<String> wsdlFileNames) {
            wsdlFileNames.each { fileName ->
                def interfaceNames = getBindingNames(fileName)
                interfaceNames.each {
                    updateInterfaceDefinition(it, fileName)
                }
            }       
        }

        void updateInterfaceDefinition(String interfaceName, String fileName) {       
            List<Interface> interfacesList = wsdlProject.interfaceList
            interfacesList.each { Interface anInterface ->
                if (anInterface instanceof WsdlInterface && interfaceName.equals(anInterface.name)) {
                    WsdlInterface wsdlInterface = (WsdlInterface) anInterface
                    wsdlInterface.updateDefinition(fileName, false)
                }
            }
        }

        void updateRequests () {
            List<Interface> interfacesList = wsdlProject.interfaceList
            interfacesList.each { Interface anInterface ->
                WsdlInterface wsdlInterface = (WsdlInterface) anInterface
                recreateRequests(wsdlInterface,false,false,true,false)
                recreateTestRequests(wsdlInterface,false,false,true,false)
            }
        }

        void saveWsdlProject() {
            wsdlProject.save()
            wsdlProject.release()

        }

}

String projectName = "/path/to/abc-soapui-project.xml" //absolute path of soapui project file
List<String> wsdlFiles = ["/path/to/service1.wsdl"] //or you can have multiple wsdls from different wsdl files which you want to update in one project
UpdateWsdls updateWsdl = new UpdateWsdls(projectName)
updateWsdl.updateInterfaceDefinitions(wsdlFiles)
updateWsdl.updateRequests()
updateWsdl.saveWsdlProject()
```

Comment: Please suggest how to use this if there is no external wsdl file.
I want to update the request based on the existing project wsdl in case there is any change in request structure.

Also suggest should this script be kept as a groovy step or inside setup script ?

Comment: You might have created project initially based on some wsdl. So, i believe that there are changes in the same wsdl file, hence you may provide that file. The script is intended for that purpose. If it is online wsdl, then you may save it and provide the location.

Comment: In case i save the wsdl in a file and provide that location in the soapUI project. How will my wsdl get updated (with new changes) when there is any change in the wsdl (service or structure), as now i am always referring to a static wsdl file that i saved. Hope you get my concern.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I am creating my test project with the wsdl that can get updated by the development team. So what i require is , a script that updates the wsdl and all requests everytime before execution (with the updated wsdl), so that in case there is any change by dev team in the request structure, it gets reflected in my soapui request and we can track the changes.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Note that soapui project needs to be updated with the updated wsdl file which might have potential schema changes from developers. The script provides does that job including updating of existing test requests from the suites. Have given a short running the script?

Comment: So as per your script we need to keep the wsdl file updated with the potential schema changes from developers. Right?
-----------------------------------------------------------------
In our case we don't know when the schema gets updated. To track such changes we need to keep on updating our wsdl and recreate our requests so that in case of any schema change our test case will fail and we will come to know of any such change in schema.
------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

I got way to update definition through goovy script. 
The below script will update the wsdl definition.
Now i need a script to recreate all my request based on the updated schema.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface

myInterface=(WsdlInterface) testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceByName("interface name");

myInterface.updateDefinition("wsdl url here", false);

log.info " WSDL definition loaded from '" + myInterface.getDefinition() + "'";
```

==============================================================

Need a script now to recreate all request based on updated schema (with keep existing values)