# sopaui update wsdl from url using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

is it possible to update wsdl file dynamically from an url?
This code point to a path where there is a static wsdl file.
How can i modify the code at second line:

```
String projectName = "C:/Users/soapui-project.xml" 
List<String> wsdlFiles = ["http://abc.zxc.io/wsdl/v1/?appname=abc version=1.0"] 
UpdateWsdls updateWsdl = new UpdateWsdls(projectName)
```

Comment: The second line is never used in the rest of the script, the next line!

Comment: the whole code is from this page = https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/blob/master/groovy/UpdateWSDLDefinition.groovy

Comment: @SiKing, looks `Templog Log` shown some parts of the script from [github](https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/blob/master/groovy/UpdateWSDLDefinition.groovy), not sure why. <br>`@Templog Log` what happended you try the above script? Not clear, what the problem is for the post? All you need is to provide the `wsdl` url. Are you using it for `rest` ? Then that is not useful and you need to update the question properly.

Comment: @Rao, i tried your script by putting the url as indicated in the above script and the error is "java.io.FileNotFoundException:"

Comment: Because that is expecting _local file_, not the _URL_. You can simply save the wsdl file locally and provide the `wsdl` file path.

Comment: i know i can save the file but i want to update dynamically, the wsdl can be updated anytime so each i do not want to check and save the wsdl file and then execute the script, the script should fetch the wsdl from the url and not a file from a folder. is this possible?

Comment: @TemplogLog, ok. may need enhancement to the [script](https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/blob/master/groovy/UpdateWSDLDefinition.groovy) to handle your case. By the way, does your wsdl contains inline `xsd` or does `wsdl` include refernces for external `xsd's` ?

Comment: @TemplogLog I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447452/soapui-how-to-update-wsdl-definition-and-recreate-requests-through-groovy-script) is what you need.